# Proxychains unable to locate file on kali linux

Tags: linux, proxy, dns, iceweasel

I'm having a problem with my kali linux and the proxychains: it outputs following error. It seems it cannot find the reference pointer for the exec or the exec has wrong info.

I have checked the resolv.conf file everything seems to be ok and also the proxychains.conf file seems to be running fine. I've tried multiple dns servers but the same error results.

Anyone has any solution ?
Output from the command line:

```
 root@kali:~# proxychains iceweasel www.google.com
 ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
 |DNS-request| www.google.com 
 can't exec proxyresolv: No such file or directory
 |DNS-response|: www.google.com is not exist
 |DNS-request| www.google.com 
 can't exec proxyresolv: No such file or directory
 |DNS-response|: www.google.com is not exist
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue, the symlink for `proxyresolv` seems to have been destroyed. Coincidence? I think not. Something to do with the latest upgrade.

Fix:

`ln -s /usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv /usr/bin/`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on

`Linux kali 3.18.0-kali3-586 #1 Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) i686 GNU/Linux`

```
root@kali:~# proxychains msfconsole
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
[*] Starting the Metasploit Framework console...-[-] Failed to connect to the database: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here's how I managed to get it up and running:

1. First make sure that this symlink is present:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv /usr/bin/
   ```
2. Comment out the `proxy_dns` line in `/etc/proxychains.conf`:

   ```
   # Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
   #proxy_dns
   ```

I haven't figured out the correct way to get this to work with `proxy_dns` enabled.

Trying again, seems to work fine.

```
root@kali:~# proxychains msfconsole
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
[*] Starting the Metasploit Framework console...|
# cowsay++
 ____________
< metasploit >
 ------------
       \   ,__,
        \  (oo)____
           (__)    )\
              ||--|| *


Trouble managing data? List, sort, group, tag and search your pentest data
in Metasploit Pro -- learn more on http://rapid7.com/metasploit

       =[ metasploit v4.11.1-2015042001 [core:4.11.1.pre.2015042001 api:1.0.0]]
+ -- --=[ 1445 exploits - 820 auxiliary - 229 post        ]
+ -- --=[ 370 payloads - 37 encoders - 8 nops             ]
+ -- --=[ Free Metasploit Pro trial: http://r-7.co/trymsp ]
```